# Critical WordPress error when trying to login the Prestashop admin panel

Tags: wordpress, apache, prestashop

I'm running WordPress at `www.domain.com`, and I'm running Prestashop at `www.sub.domain.com`. As you can see I'm using a subdomain to run a shop.

I'm hosting this on *Hostinger*.

The problem is that when I try to go to **Prestashop's admin panel**, it throws a **WordPress** error, which makes no sense. **Now I'm unable to login the admin panel.**

<s>This error first appeared after updating WordPress to the last version</s>. **This error appears after updating Prestashop to 1.7.7.1**. As I said before, there's no WordPress installation at the subdomain. Could it be an Apache configuration error, such an .htaccess file?

I'm trying to figure out where is this problem coming from. No .htaccess files have been edited manually.

After enabling the debug mode in PHP **this is the error it throws**:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Expected to find class "PrestaShopBundle\Controller\Admin\Configure\index" in file "/home/user394857/domains/domain.com/public_html/sub/src/PrestaShopBundle/Controller/Admin/Configure/index.php" while importing services from resource "/home/user394857/domains/domain.com/public_html/sub/app/../src/PrestaShopBundle/Controller/*", but it was not found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource. in /home/user394857/domains/domain.com/public_html/sub/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/FileLoader.php:157 Stack trace: #0 /home/user394857/domains/domain.com/public_html/sub/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/FileLoader.php(57): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\FileLoader->findClasses('PrestaShopBundl...', '/home/u10247759...', '/home/u10247759...') #1 /home/user394857/domains/domain.com/public_html/sub/vendor/ in /home/user394857/domains/domain.com/public_html/sub/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/FileLoader.php on line 168

[image]

Comment: A screenshot of a generic error message doesn't tell us anything either so you'll want to have a look at the server error log to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @cabrerahector Log added

Comment: It seems prestashop has an error, but because its installed in a subfolder of the wordpress root the error handler of wordpress processes it. I would recommend to use diffrent root folders for wordpress and prestashop

Comment: @JasperB Prestashop is not installed in a subfolder of wordpress. The public_html/tienda folder is a folder automatically generated after creating a subdomain.

Comment: ok so if I'm correct wordpress is installed in "/home/user394857/domains/domain.com/public_html/somefolder" and presta shop in "/home/user394857/domains/domain.com/public_html/tienda" ?

Comment: @JasperB No, WordPress is installed in `public_html`, but it should not interfere with the `public_html/tienda` as it's one of the subdomains my hosting provides. Now I've seen this error happens when updating Prestashop, not Wordpress. Updating the post now.

Comment: @MikelGranero This does mean that the shop is installed inside the root directory of wordpress this could be causing the issue. you can also verify this by going to www.domain.com/tienda. Instead of installing it in `public_html/tienda` you should install it in a directory like `public_html2`

Comment: @JasperB No. The way to go to the shop is `www.tienda.domain.com`, and **not** `www.domain.com/tienda`. That's why I'm telling you it's a subdomain folder and not a simple folder created in WordPress's root folder.

Comment: regardless of it being a subdomain, the physical folder on the server is stored inside the WordPress directory. And my suspicions are that the .htaccess of wordpress is somehow  mucking up the requests made to the presta shop.

Comment: What Jasper said. To the server, Prestashop is located in a subfolder inside `public_html`, where WordPress also lives. Move your `tienda` subdomain outside the `public_html` folder and test again.

Comment: Also, read the actual error message: Prestashop is complaining about a missing PHP class. Maybe the update went wrong and your Prestashop setup is now (partially) corrupted (as in missing/corrupted/non-readable files/folders.)

Comment: @JasperB I'll take a look, but my hosting provider doesn't allow to move the subdomain folder (tienda) outside the public_html folder as it's automatically generated.As cabrerahector said, Prestashop might be corrupted. I'll try to restore a previous version and check back.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was that **the Prestashop setup was corrupted** after an automatic update that was triggered from my hosting's cpanel. I restored a previous version of the Prestashop files and now it's working.